# Is it safe to wrap conversion macros from "caml/mlvalues.h" like Val_int, Int_val with some functions?

Tags: c++, macros, ocaml

I implement a bridge from Ocaml to C++. As I know, only functions that bound in the OCaml side with using **external** keyword should be defined as C function (it is necessary for linker). So they should be contained in `extern "C" { ... }` block. Except for this point, I can use C++ code as I want (include using in functions declared in  **extern "C" ** block).

To improve readability I want to wrap macros from "caml/mlvalues.h" like the following

```cpp
namespace Caml { 
  namespace Value {
    int to_int(value x) { return Int_val(x); }
    value of_int(int x) { return Val_int(x); }
    ...
  }
}
```

and to use `Caml::Value::to_int` and `Caml::Value::of_int` instead of original `Int_val` and `Val_int`. But it looks dangerous for me because of macros, bitwise copying, and scopes. Is it safe to use a facade like described above?

Comment: I don't know the `ocaml` library, but is it required that you only _"pass"_ a variable of the type `value` to `Int_val`?  If so I would prefer using your `Caml::Value::to_int`, over the `Int_val` because the preprocess only does a search and replace without type checking so `Int_val(x)` becomes `((int) ((x) >> 1))` regardless of what type `x` is. For `Caml::Value::to_int` the compiler will do type checks.

Comment: Why do you think that it should not be safe to do that? Do you have a use-case in mind where this would a problem in your opinion?

Comment: @t.niese A lot of macros from "caml/mlvalues.h" works with OCaml Garbage Collector, they register something in GC, etc. because value object is the object from OCaml heap https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s:c-gc-harmony . For example, I can't wrap macros CAMLparam(x) because it is necessary to keep it in the same scope. I asked not only about Int_val and Val_int but about other macros too, because I am not sure that wrapping of each of them has no dangerous side effects.

Comment: Yes for `CAMLparam` it would be indeed a problem. There might be still some ways how you could encapsulate it, but as I don't know ocaml it is not easy to give a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong with your wrappers for `Int_val` and `Val_int`. The wrapper for the `Field` macro would need to return an l-value, but there is nothing difficult about it:

```cpp
value &field(value *x, int y) { return Field(x, y); }
```

I suppose the more interesting code would come from a wrapper around `Is_block` so as to make it a bit more idiomatic:

```cpp
value *as_block(value x)
{ if (Is_block(x)) return (value *)x;
  else return nullptr; }

// usage:
if (value *ptr = as_block(x)) {
  foo(field(ptr, 0));
} else {
  bar(to_int(x));
}
```

For extra type safety, you could replace the type `value *` of `field` and `as_block` by an opaque pointer:

```cpp
struct block;
block *as_block(value) ...
value &field(block *, int) ...
```

Comment: Why do you cast value to value* `(value *)x`? I see this firstly, as I know `Field(v, index)` works with value type directly

Comment: That is a matter of code philosophy. You can either live in an untyped world where everything has type `value`, or you can add a bit of type safety by explicitly marking values known to be pointers as such. By the way, `Field` works with anything that can safely be converted to `value*`.

Answer (score 1):

The value functions should be declared as const expression where possible and static inline otherwise. Apart from that wrapping them in other function is perfectly fine.

The CAMLparam macros on the other hand open a scope that is closed by CAMLreturn macros. And it's annoying that you have to specify the number of arguments for it anway.

You should rewrite them from scratch in C++ using vardiac templates and RAII style. So instead of opening a new scope and declaring some hidden variables you should have a real object that registers the arguments with the GC in the constructor and unregisters them in the destructor.